# Can the word leitmotif can be used this way?

Tags: word-usage

https://www.scmp.com/comment/insight-opinion/article/2148249/india-proves-democracy-no-longer-fit-purpose-while-chinas

> Such odious tactics are democracy’s leitmotif globally, as Brexit and
>   Donald Trump’s election demonstrate. In combination, they suggest that
>   democracy is not fit for purpose, especially in developing nations,
>   particularly since there is a clear alternative: China’s political
>   system.

Leitmotif is defined as:

> 1. (Classical Music) music a recurring short melodic phrase or theme used, esp in Wagnerian music dramas, to suggest a character, thing,
>      etc
> 2. (Literary & Literary Critical Terms) an often repeated word, phrase, image, or theme in a literary work

It seems to fit the second definition, but as we can see it's a literary term, so how do you explain the way it is used here?

Theme is defined as:

> 1. an idea or topic expanded in a discourse, discussion, etc
> 2. (in literature, music, art, etc) a unifying idea, image, or motif, repeated or developed throughout a work
> 3. (Music, other) music a group of notes forming a recognizable melodic unit, often used as the basis of the musical material in a
>      composition
> 4. (Education) a short essay, esp one set as an exercise for a student
> 5. (Grammar) linguistics the first major constituent of a sentence, usually but not necessarily the subject. In the sentence history I do
>      like, "history" is the theme of the sentence, even though it is the
>      object of the verb
> 6. (Linguistics) grammar another word for root19, stem19
> 7. (Historical Terms) (in the Byzantine Empire) a territorial unit consisting of several provinces under a military commander
> 8. (modifier) planned or designed round one unifying subject, image, etc: a theme holiday.

It seems to fit the first, so can leitmotif mean a recurring idea? Can we use it to mean a simple thing such as a recurring idea? Is an odious tactic an idea? I guess everything is an idea, but does it justify the usage?

Comment: It's referring to odious tactics. Ergo, it is 2).

Answer (score 1):

> Such odious tactics are democracy’s leitmotif globally ...

Means that the tactics  being discussed are common, often repeated, in countries with a democratic form of government. This is a somewhat extended or figurative use of "leitmotif", extending the sense of "an often repeated word, phrase, image, or theme" which is itself a generalization or extension of the musical sense. Personally, i would not have used "leitmotif" in that construction, but I have no trouble understanding it.  The writer is implying that such actions or tactics are commonly associated with democracy, indeed that they form a sort of identifying signature  for democratic societies. This picks up on the original musical use, where a leitmotif is used to identify or mark the entrance of a character, much as a "theme song" or 'signature tune" is in other forms of entertainment. The writer is saying that the tactics s/he deplores are, in effect, democracy's theme song or signature. The author is analyzing current events as if they were part of a literary or dramatic creation, to some extent.

Comment: I don't have trouble understanding it, but I am not sure if this type of overextension is allowed.

Comment: question is if a tactic is a word, phrase, image, or theme, and if it's a theme if it's an idea developed or expanded throughout a work. that's why I don't really think it makes sense.